# Wordpress json api error while generate_auth_cookie

Tags: wordpress

I'm having problem with wordpress json Api When login the user. Currently I'm Using Wordpress version 4.5.1 with listed below plugin:

[image]

Here are the step I follow:

1) Generate nonce

http://example.org/api/get_nonce/?controller=user&method=generate_auth_cookie

Below is Response:

```
{"status":"ok","controller":"user","method":"generate_auth_cookie","nonce":"4d080ff7b8"}
```

2) Generate Auth Cookie

http://example.org/api/user/generate_auth_cookie/?nonce=+4d080ff7b8&username=example&password=example

Below is Response:

```
{"status":"error","error":"SSL is not enabled. Either use _https_ or provide 'insecure' var as insecure=cool to confirm you want to use http protocol."}
```

Why I'm Getting this error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that `JSON API User` and `JSON API Auth` plugins allow by default only connections over https.

In order to turn off this setting, you should send an extra parameter in the request:

```
insecure=cool
```

So try the following request:

```
http://example.org/api/user/generate_auth_cookie/?nonce=+4d080ff7b8&username=example&password=example&insecure=cool
```

Comment: Also, it seems that all the functionality of `JSON API Auth` plugin (Generate Auth Cookie for user authentication, Validate Auth Cookie, Get Current User Info) is also included in `JSON API User`. Why are you using both? I think that `JSON API User` is enough.